# Why didn't Luke commit suicide long ago?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

In *Star Wars: The Last Jedi*, we learned that

> Luke had no plan to return from his exile. He wanted to end Jedi order with him.

If that was the case, why didn't he simply commit suicide in the beginning of his exile? Why did he remain alive on Ahch-To until someone from outside contacted him?

Comment: This is a perfectly good question. Anyone wants to bother justifying the downvote?

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To: It describes suicide as a simple solution — I guess some of us feel not super-keen about that.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite There is a difference between the subject IRL vs the movies.  Especially since in the Star Wars canon an afterlife is shown to exist.  BTW I suggest you don't read Philip José Farmer's Riverworld series.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - right. Because in Star Wars, suicide isn't shown as a simple solution. Ever. Not in Episodes IV (OB1), VI (the A-Wing pilot), and VIII (spoiler but you know who). Wait. It is depicted just that way.

Comment: Because that was Rian Johnson's idea, and Luke was already shown to be alive in The Force Awakens. Someone who wants to die alone doesn't leave a droid with 90% of a map and clues how to find him.

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To: I’m not sure it’s portrayed as a simple solution in those instances (no one gets on the radio and says hey, Gold Four, *just* commit suicide), more a desperate sacrifice in an attempt to save others in a moment when no other options are available. And to quibble, Obi-wan wasn’t actually suicide. Vader killed him.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - he raised his lightsaber and let Vader off him without parrying.

Comment: Because it is a frivolous question. Most people do not become suicidal when they lose their jobs or their religion.

Comment: @JDoe: Perhaps not most, but I think those are exactly the sort of things to push some people. Many suicides must be due to loss of hope; whether or not you think them morally justified they certainly happen.

Comment: Out of Universe explanation: Star Wars is also meant to be watched by a younger audience. Killing the character by suicide would propably disturb the younger audience

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Luke didn't commit suicide because he didn't want to end his life prematurely; He merely stated that he wished the *Jedi Order* to end with him. It is possible that suicidal ideations and/or attempts are covered in events not yet depicted in canon, but, in the film itself, Luke is not shown to *hate* his life in exile, but rather the contrary:

- He undertakes complex actions to get nutrition from different sources, including fishing and [dairy](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Green_milk).
- His clothes, home and other belongings are in good repair despite what appears to be very harsh weather on the island.
- Finally, he lives in [a small community of Lanai](http://www.starwars.com/databank/caretakers), and so, regardless of how much social interaction his daily life actually entails, he *chose* to live near these people and also was not ostracised by them.

In other words, his life was rather full — despite being confined to a small island. Someone committed to ending their own life would likely not display the traits listed above, as they all entail investing a significant amount of effort and energy. To the contrary, it suggests that he is quite committed to his life in exile. This strongly suggests that he is not severely depressed, even if he does act somewhat disgruntled **towards Rey when discussing the Jedi and the Force**, which are topics he has distanced himself from and doesn't enjoy revisiting for reasons explained in the film.

Comment: Does life being full or not full really matter here when he was going to become a force ghost?

Comment: @Bat there is no evidence suggesting that that was his ultimate intention, and even if it was, why would enjoying life be antithetical to becoming a Force ghost? I'm going to die someday too, so why should I care about my life now? Actually, since he deliberately cut himself off from the Force, one can assume that he had intentions of **not** becoming a Force ghost.

Comment: `I'm going to die someday too, so why should I care about my life now?` ~> Because you don't know for sure that afterlife exists.

Comment: Also, if his intentions was to fully cut himself from the Force, he wouldn't have chosen Ahch-To. He could have gone to any random planet.

Comment: @Bat Christians, Jews, and Muslims all believe in an afterlife, and not all of those people believe suicide is a sin; So why don't those commit suicide to get to Heaven more quickly?

Comment: @Bat "Also, if his intentions was to fully cut himself from the Force, he wouldn't have chosen Ahch-To. He could have gone to any random planet" > There is no evidence that he **arrived** at Ach-To intending to cut himself off from the Force. I honestly think this is just baiting now; It's no longer related to the OP.

Comment: Because those religions put lots of conditions to earn a ticket to heaven. Also, people's beliefs aren't that strong. BTW, some religious extremists who believe that committing the act would give his/her ticket to heaven indeed go for suicide bombings etc.

Comment: @Bat I think your question would be better served on [Philosophy SE](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/) since there is no "religion" or "Jedi" SE. It's not about Luke committing suicide; It's you trying to ask indirectly about theological issues of the Jedi religion. In fact, it's likely you've indirectly answered your own question (why Luke doesn't commit suicide), but you're too invested in your stance to see it.

Comment: @Bat This is the best answer so far. Luke did not wish to die; he only wished the Jedi Order to not continue on after his death. He did cut himself off from the Force while he was there as well. I would need to watch the film again, but this is acknowledged within. In addition, despite Luke not telling anyone where he was he did leave clues to find him. Whether this was something he did deliberately (despite his wishes) or while being influenced by the Force we do not know; but did. And as I mentioned above he also chose that planet because it was the "birth place" of the Jedi Order.

Comment: @errantlinguist: Not to get too far into the weeds, but Christian prohibitions on suicide (and the idea of it being a mortal sin) are actually based on them discouraging just such an argument that suicide is better than to live a long life and fall into sin. Sure, there are also theological arguments involving "rejecting God's greatest gift" and the difficulty of repenting for murder (of oneself) after committing suicide, but primarily, it was to discourage people from killing themselves or children who were unlikely to stay innocent, particularly since Apocalypticism was common.

Answer (score 5):

There is no direct answer in canon yet (hopefully, future TLJ novelization will help), but one thing we do know from canon is that the Jedi tend to follow the will of the Force. As such, unless the Force led him to "join with the Force" like Yoda, he wouldn't deliberately end a life, even his, "just because"

Comment: Except that he'd intentionally cut himself off from the Force. He was unaware of the attack on the Hosnian system, the death of Solo, etc etc.

Comment: @Valorum - was it Luke, or was it the location shielding him (ala Yoda on Dagobah)?

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To - it was absolutely Luke.  Rey had no issues with access to the Force or being guided by it, and Yoda on Dagobah had no problems using the Force or being visited by Force Ghosts.  For Luke to be undetectable at all in the Force, he must have cut himself off.  Yoda remained disguised the whole time he lived on Dagobah, even when actively using the force.

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To - Visual Dictionary says that "*Despite living on an island drenched in the Force, Luke has cut off all connection to the mystical energy field*"

Comment: @Valorum If he intentionally cut himself off from the Force, why did he choose to go to Ahch-To? He could have gone to any random planet.

Comment: @Bat He went to that planet specifically because it was the "birth place" of the Jedi Order.

Comment: @Odin1806 - that makes no sense at all.

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To Why is that? From the films we know that he was searching for the first temple, found the first temple, and exiled himself there... what is missing?

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To God, seriously, fill in the blanks a bit. Luke forms a Jedi Academy, fails miserably, gets depressed, goes searching for the Jedi temple, does a bunch of soul-searching, and finally decides that, ultimately, the Jedi Order would be better off not existing. It was nearly spelled out that way in the film. This isn't Memento-level plot deduction.

Comment: @errantlinguist - how does anything you say relate to him wanting to end his life specifically on Ahch-To?

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To maybe he doesn't care. Maybe he didn't intend to down his X-Wing but was flying drunk and got stranded. Maybe he really liked the Caretakers and wanted to help out. Maybe the sea breeze alleviated a chronic health condition. Maybe all of the above. Why does everything have to be spelled out? That would make the movie completely boring.